# `file` fails to identify file extensions for several file types

Tags: macos, mime-types

On macOS—and perhaps other *nix systems—the [`file`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(command)) command’s `--extension` option outputs `???` most of the time, to the point it’s useless.

Examples using [the example PNG from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png):

```
$ file /Users/name/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1-1.png
/Users/vitor/Desktop/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1-1.png: PNG image data, 800 x 600, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced

$ file --mime-type --brief 
/Users/name/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1-1.png

$ file --extension --brief /Users/name/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1-1.png
???
```

It can identify the type of most files I throw at it but not their extension, be them PNG, MKV, MP4, PDF, …

Why is that? Why include an option that seldom gives meaningful information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `man file`

> ```
>  --extension
>          Print a slash-separated list of valid extensions for the file type found.
> ```

This depends on what `file` can identify by looking at the file contents.  For example if you make random file it can't identify it

```
A1398% echo "test" >> test
A1398% file --extension test**
test:    ???
```

If you zip it with [keka](https://www.keka.io/en/) it will identify it as 7z/cb7 format (one of the few file formats it seems to identify).

```
A1398% file --extension test**
test:    ???
test.7z: 7z/cb7
```

Even if you rename it with a different file extension - for example here I used **.jpg**

```
A1398% mv test.7z test_renamed.jpg
A1398% file --extension test**
test:             ???
test_renamed.jpg: 7z/cb7
```

The reason it is found is it is defined with a `!:ext` in `/usr/share/file/magic/compress`

```
# 7-zip archiver, from Thomas Klausner (wiz@danbala.tuwien.ac.at)
# https://www.7-zip.org or DOC/7zFormat.txt
#
0   string      7z\274\257\047\034  7-zip archive data,
>6  byte        x           version %d
>7  byte        x           \b.%d
!:mime  application/x-7z-compressed
!:ext 7z/cb7
```

Mojave uses version 5.33 and  *.png* is not found as it isn't defined in `/usr/share/file/magic/images` - the `!:ext` tag is missing :

```
# Standard PNG image.
0   string      \x89PNG\x0d\x0a\x1a\x0a\x00\x00\x00\x0DIHDR PNG image data
!:mime  image/png
!:strength +10
>16 use     png-ihdr

# Apple CgBI PNG image.
0   string      \x89PNG\x0d\x0a\x1a\x0a\x00\x00\x00\x04CgBI
>24 string      \x00\x00\x00\x0DIHDR    PNG image data (CgBI)
!:mime  image/png
!:strength +10
>>32    use     png-ihdr
```

In the latest version (5.37) of the [source](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/images) *.png* is defined as an extension.

```
# Standard PNG image.
0   string      \x89PNG\x0d\x0a\x1a\x0a\x00\x00\x00\x0DIHDR PNG image data
!:mime  image/png
!:ext   png
!:strength +10
>16 use     png-ihdr

# Apple CgBI PNG image.
0   string      \x89PNG\x0d\x0a\x1a\x0a\x00\x00\x00\x04CgBI
>24 string      \x00\x00\x00\x0DIHDR    PNG image data (CgBI)
!:mime  image/png
!:ext   png
!:strength +10
>>32    use     png-ihdr
```

The reason you aren't finding *.png* therefore appears to be because Apple is using old version.

The more general question of why `file` doesn't identify some particular file type is because someone has to identify something unique in the structure of the file and add it to the definitions.